# Style N elements based on a number in a parent class

Tags: html, css

I'm currently building out a grid using only CSS & HTML and have come a bit unstuck.

Looking to count from each instance of colHead and apply a negative margin to the 2 following colSpan1 items. This works great on the first one but is disregarded any subsequent ones.

Is there a way to count from each colHead regardless of where they appear in the container?

The loop is dynamic so there is no option to add extra classes into the HTML to achieve this.

Can do it the following way but it's a bit messy (especially when introducing more columns) and was hoping there's a cleaner way:

.colCount2 .colHead + .colSpan1, .colCount2 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 { margin-top: -2em; }

Thanks for your time.

```css
[class^="colCount"] { display: grid; grid-gap: 2em; grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr); width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; }
.colCount2 .colHead { grid-column: span 12; }
.colCount2 .colHead ~ .colSpan1:nth-of-type(-n+2) { margin-top: -2em; }
.colCount2 .colSpan1 { grid-column: span 6; }
```

```html
<div class="colCount2">
    <span class="colHead">
        <h2>Two Columns (colCount2)</h2>
    </span>
    <div class="colSpan1">
        <p><strong>colSpan1</strong> <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam aliquam aliquam sapien, non auctor orci iaculis sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="colSpan1">
        <p><strong>colSpan1</strong> <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam aliquam aliquam sapien, non auctor orci iaculis sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="colSpan1">
        <p><strong>colSpan1</strong> <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam aliquam aliquam sapien, non auctor orci iaculis sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <span class="colHead">
        <h2>Two Columns (colCount2)</h2>
    </span>
    <div class="colSpan1">
        <p><strong>colSpan1</strong> <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam aliquam aliquam sapien, non auctor orci iaculis sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="colSpan1">
        <p><strong>colSpan1</strong> <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam aliquam aliquam sapien, non auctor orci iaculis sit amet.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a great case for using a CSS preprocessor to efficiently write those rules. I'm not sure I'm extrapolating your intended grid system correctly, but with [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/), you could write the following—

```
$cols: 2, 3, 4, 6, 12;

@each $col in $cols {
  .colCount#{$col} .colHead {
    $adjascentSelector: '';
    @for $i from 1 through $col {
      $adjascentSelector: $adjascentSelector + ' + .colSpan1';
      & #{$adjascentSelector} {
        grid-column: span (12 / $col);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

—which compiles to—

```css
.colCount2 .colHead + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 6;
}
.colCount2 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 6;
}

.colCount3 .colHead + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 4;
}
.colCount3 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 4;
}
.colCount3 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 4;
}

.colCount4 .colHead + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
.colCount4 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
.colCount4 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
.colCount4 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.colCount6 .colHead + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
.colCount6 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
.colCount6 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
.colCount6 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
.colCount6 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
.colCount6 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.colCount12 .colHead + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 1;
}
.colCount12 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 1;
}
.colCount12 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 1;
}
.colCount12 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 1;
}
.colCount12 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 1;
}
.colCount12 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 1;
}
.colCount12 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 1;
}
.colCount12 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 1;
}
.colCount12 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 1;
}
.colCount12 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 1;
}
.colCount12 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 1;
}
.colCount12 .colHead + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 + .colSpan1 {
  grid-column: span 1;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately adding in classes manually is not an option, should've explained that. Will add this info to the post, thanks.

Comment: @Barry I've updated my answer based on your comment and revision.

Comment: thanks for the update – yet another reason to help in convincing the boss that it's time to start using a CSS preprocessor. I'm guessing there's no combination of selectors (other than manually doing the above) in CSS to achieve this?

Comment: @Barry not that I'm aware of